# Node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'Rx'

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, rxjs, observable

Can you tell me why below behavior with `rxjs/Rx`? I'm using `VS code V 1.14.1`.

This works:

```
import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

and

```
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

**But** This is not working.

```
import { Rx } from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

> node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'Rx'.

Comment: You really don't want to do that, as this will certainly mess up any later "tree shaking" you probably want to do when bundling down the track. Instead you should be importing the parts you actually need. i.e `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';` And if you want additional operators then you can globally do things like `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';` as needed. But importing all of `Rx` is not something you really want to do here.

Comment: @NeilLunn I need to use this `Rx.Observable.timer(3000).subscribe()`.That is why I need it.So how can I do that without `Rx` import?

Comment: Do `import 'rxjs/add/operator/timer'` then. Don't import **ALL** of the library namespace just to get a additional method.

Comment: Great.Hope you'll put this as an answer too.Please provide me a little bit more about the `tree shaking`?  @NeilLunn

Answer (score 15):

its rxjs issue , i fixed it using 
**npm install rxjs-compat**

Comment: Thank you! Solved!

Comment: Worked for me - Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

try with this:

import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/internal/BehaviorSubject';

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I solved the issue by installing `npm install rxjs`.

Use `import * as Rx from "rxjs";` instead of `import * as Rx from "rxjs/Rx";`. Just remove the Rx after the slash.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: **Rxjs** does not have or export **Rx**

so, `Import {Rx} from 'rxjs'`  will not work

If you want to import something specific like an Observable, you can do:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Alternatively, you can import entire **Rxjs** and give it an alias of **Rx** as follows:

`Import * as Rx from 'rxjs'`

Answer (score 0):

> node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'Rx'.

Because it doesn't have an exported member named `Rx`.

## More

You cannot `import` something that isn't `export`ed.

Comment: If it doesn't have `import` member how this works `import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';`? What are the other options to work this?

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install @reactivex/rxjs

import * as Rx from 'rxjs';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently. Fixed it using below steps

remove node_modules using **rm -rf node_modules/**

set rxjs v6.0.0, rxjs-compat v6.0.0 in **package.json**

run **npm install**

run **ionic serve**

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same issue . This seems to be the problem because they  are using version of RxJs which you might not be using.

I will suggest to just downgrade angular flex to 5.0.0-beta.14.

reference : https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/702